# Power consumption LCD display on digital watch 12h/24h

Tags: lcd

just a fun question:
When I was a child, I thought that displaying my casio F91w in 12h mode rather than 24h will make my battery last longer since there are fewer segments displayed.
when i saw this graph i realized it wasn't that simple.
Does the energy consumption depend on the number of segments displayed and does switching to 12h mode increase the battery life?
Was i wrong as a child?

on the graph, we can see that the consumption of an on or off segment seems the same. Is it true?
[image]

Comment: it's hard to say whether you were wrong. Why do you think you were wrong? What has been your thought process so far? Where do you think the energy goes? **Edit** your question to include your considerations!

Comment: hi Marcus, I edited. the simple question i am asking myself is does the battery life increase in 12h mode?

Comment: yes, but *why* do you wonder? What's your understanding of power consumed here? We can't be explaining all of electronics up to the point where we can explain how much (if any) power is consumed more by an on-segment; that's just too much text. We depend on you to explicitly state what your considerations are, and what your current understanding of where the power goes is. Which you haven't done. Please give us *any* hint as where to start explaining!

Comment: just to know if I was right to think that when I was a kid. nothing more.I don't need a very elaborate answer

Comment: so, an answer stating "you were wrong" is **Really** all you're looking for?! (I can add a "but it's complicated", too)

Comment: ok, on the graph, we can see that the consumption of an on or off segment seems the same. is it true ? I just wanted to know if I understood this graphic correctly

Comment: no, that is not true. Now you're starting to *describe your understanding*; that's exactly what I've been asking you to do, thank you :) Please do edit your question to include that description of your understanding.

Comment: Ok, thanks for adding that. But: how did you conclude that the power consumption would be the same?

Comment: In theory, the power consumption of keeping segment lit is higher than keeping it unlit, due to the fact that a lit segment needs to be driven with AC that changes polarity. But in practice, the difference can be so insignificant that it may not make any difference.

Comment: Marcus, we can see that the power supply time is the same for on and off (4 spikes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single segment of an LCD display can be modeled by a (very tiny) capacitor. The segment is ON when there is a voltage difference between the capacitors terminals.

The LCD gets damaged if the segments/capacitors are driven with a DC voltage. That's why the LCD driver always needs to toggle the signal polarity on both terminals. (Check the mean voltage in the graph above: It's 0V).

For driving the segment in ON state, the capacitor is recharged a lot (switching losses!), where in the OFF state, there is no voltage difference between Backplane and Segment terminals.

So your assumption is right: **The fewer segment are in the ON state, the less current is used.**